# DataGrid View Not Showing Newly Added Record using Access Database

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, oledbconnection, oledbdataadapter

I am new to C# and I want to do this ASAP as I've had this problem since past week. I have tried a few approaches and not yet gotten the correct output. Here is my code:

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            String itemcode = tbItemCode.Text.ToString();
            String shade = tbShade.Text.ToString();
            String rollnumber = tbRollNumber.Text.ToString();

            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Eranga\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\RollAllocationModel\RollAllocationModel\Roll.mdb;Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=admin");
            String deletequery = "DELETE FROM TabRoll WHERE (ItemCode = '" + itemcode + "') AND (Shade = '" + shade + "') AND (RollNumber = '" + rollnumber + "')";
            //String deletequery = "SELECT * FROM TabRoll";
            //code by query builder ----> DELETE FROM TabRoll WHERE (ItemCode = '" + itemcode + "') AND (Shade = '" + shade + "') AND (RollNumber = '" + length + "');
            conn.Open();

            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(deletequery, conn);
            OleDbCommandBuilder cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
            bSource.DataSource = dt;


            dataGridView1.EndEdit();
            bSource.EndEdit();
            da.Update(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;

            conn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Data deleted");
        }
        catch (Exception exceptionObj)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exceptionObj.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Why doesn't the DataGrid does not update with the new record.

Comment: You get any exception or5 error message? What is your `selectQueryString` looks like when you debug your code? What is your column types and what are the values of `itemcode`, `shade`, `ml` and `fr`?

Comment: what exception type you are getting...

Comment: There is no error showing with the exception, previously was the wrong code.... here is the code which is not given the correct output. In here delete is functioning properly. But I want to close the application and restart to view the changes. What i want is to show the updated datagridview without that deleted value.
Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Dear All, The problem is, this code functioning well. But the data grid view is not refresh itself when the delete buuton pressed. I want the data grid with new values. I don't know how to do it. Actually it is like refreshing the grid view.I am sorry, that I couldn't manage it...

Comment: SOLVED

I have Create a method to refresh the connection and then it worked well.

Thank you all for your comments. 

[Soner Gönül](http://stackoverflow.com/users/447156/soner-gonul) and  [Pradeep Kesharwani](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2739432/pradeep-kesharwani) Thank you very much!